# which R package provides functionality similar to pythons urllib

Tags: python, r, url, response, urllib3

My task is to port a snipped of python code which uses python `urllib` to R.
This is the entire python code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/"

params = {
  "from": "ACC+ID",
  "to": "ENSEMBL_ID",
  "format": "tab",
  "query": "P40925 P40926 O43175 Q9UM73 P97793"
}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
data = data.encode("utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
  response = f.read()
print(response.decode("utf-8"))
```

I am not to keen to use `paste` and `paste0` to build url's manually in R.
What I did find is the R `urltools` package.
But it does not help me with url-encoding the data as `urllib.parse.urlencode` does.

What would be the R package to use to re-implement the python code? Or should I use `reticulate`?

Thank you

Comment: Definitely not `reticulate` for such a simple task. Beside `httr` as expressed in the answer, take a look also at `RCurl` or `curl`, both giving a low level interface to `curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=httr) should get the job done:

```r
url <- "https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/"

params = list(
  from = "ACC+ID",
  to = "ENSEMBL_ID",
  format = "tab",
  query = "P40925 P40926 O43175 Q9UM73 P97793"
)

r <- httr::POST(url, body = params, encode = "form")
cat(httr::content(r))
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#> From To
#> P40925   ENSG00000014641
#> P40926   ENSG00000146701
#> O43175   ENSG00000092621
#> Q9UM73   ENSG00000171094
#> P97793   ENSMUSG00000055471
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>